# Is there a way to get information from coredumpctl via the API

Tags: debugging, systemd

I would like to get a list of executable crash reports (core-file) in my Python code and ask more about the coredump stacktrace and send that information on my email.

Please suggest me way or API for talk with `systemd-coredump` service especially I want to have API with `coredumpctl`.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I make little research and found `python3-systemd` Python module provide `journal.Reader` abstraction and when we have entity with `COUREDUMP` prefix we can process that entity and process journal message or event access to `coredump` file.

Comment: Did you succeed?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [small Python helper script](https://gist.github.com/mic-e/d7231332a01ce8fa13452223fc09e03e) that uses journal.Reader to retrieve the core dump information and is more automation-friendly than `coredumpctl`.

The core code section concerning the journal interaction is:

```py
def get_journal_entries(match):
    """
    Returns all journal entries that match the given matcher.
    """
    reader = systemd.journal.Reader()
    reader.add_match(match)
    yield from reader

for entry in get_journal_entries("CODE_FUNC=submit_coredump"):
    try:
        coredump = entry["COREDUMP_FILENAME"]
        program = entry["COREDUMP_EXE"]
        timestamp = entry["COREDUMP_TIMESTAMP"]
    except KeyError:
        continue
```

I'm not sure whether matching by `CODE_FUNC` is the best idea, but it works on my machine.